# Async Django MQTT Client cannot re-connect pg-pool after 24 hours

Tags: django, postgresql, python-asyncio, mqtt, pgpool

Let me tell you my structure and problem. I have sync and async containers on K8. These pods are running via this command in my docker-entrypoint.sh `gunicorn myappname.wsgi:application --worker-class gevent --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`. In the async ones, I run some MQTT Clients (`paho.mqtt.client`). This is my custom `apps.py` that runs clients asynchronously:

```
import asyncio
import importlib
import sys
from os import environ
from django.apps import AppConfig, apps
from django.db import connection
from .server import MQTTConsumer  # inherited from paho.mqtt.Client
from .consumers import ResponseConsumer
class CustomMqttConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'custom.mqtt'

    def ready(self):
        for _app in apps.app_configs.keys():
            topic_patterns = [
                ('$share/my-app/response', ResponseConsumer)
            ]
            
            connection.close()
            for _topic, _consumer in topic_patterns:
                asyncio.run(MQTTConsumer()(topic=_topic, consumer=_consumer))
```

Everything works perfectly until 24 hours passed after the first init of my consumers. After 24 hours, I get `connection closed` error for each MQTT request from my db (in this case pg-pool) BUT when I open a shell in my async container (`docker exec -it <container_id> bash`) and get in the django shell (`python manage.py shell`) I can use my models and filter my DB while my consumers throwing that error.

I checked my pg-pool (`show pool_processes`) before and after restarting my async pods and saw that everything works perfectly fine after reboot. New connections seen in the `pool_processes` and my consumers keep getting and processing the mqtt requests without any error. I keep track of these errors and noticed that it keeps happening every 24 hours.

My async pods receive 300K MQTT messages almost every second. I thought I can check the DB connection for each coming message and re-connect if its necessary but I believe it will cause me some performance problems.

Versions:

```
...
Django==5.0.2
paho-mqtt=2.0.0
...
```

Images:

```
bitnami/pgpool:latest
postgres:15
```

no extra params are defined in settings.py or anywhere else.

Looking for your comment or advice. Thanks from now.